# Advanced Custom Fields and frontend posting

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a frontend form that crates a new custom post type single. Is there anyway to update the ACF meta from this form?

```
<?php if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {


    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $description,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_category' => 3,  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'post_status'   => 'private',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, etc.
        'post_type' => 'door', // Use a custom post type if you want to
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_name' => 'service',
        'meta_key'      => 'archive_job',
        'meta_value'    => 'red',
    );
    wp_set_object_terms($pid, $_POST['terms'], 'child');
    wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
    wp_redirect( $current_url );

                    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_pos
} // end IF

// Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post', 'add_post_meta' , 'update_post_meta'); 

?>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the `update_field()` function provided through ACF: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

Answer (score 0):

ACF meta are saved in database as basic [custom field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). So you can use for example function add_post_meta() with values add_post_meta($post_id, 'field_name', $field_value); after wp_insert_post($post); function.

example code:

```php
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $description,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_category' => 3,  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'post_status'   => 'private',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, etc.
        'post_type' => 'door', // Use a custom post type if you want to
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_name' => 'service',
        'meta_key'      => 'archive_job',
        'meta_value'    => 'red',
    );
    wp_set_object_terms($pid, $_POST['terms'], 'child');
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'field_name', $field_value);
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
    wp_redirect( $current_url );
```